# backpack location not found

Tags: localization, laravel-backpack

I have "ru" location in my config/app.php

And I even published lang files - it can be seen at screenshot

But I see lang code-strings in my view... What's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible that Backpack doesn’t have Russian translation for those strings yet.

It’s never a good idea to have both “locale” and “fallback_locale” to the same language. This is what happens - your users see the lang keys instead of something they might understand (like English).

I suggest you use “en” as you “fallback_locale” and translate to Russian yourself. Also consider submitting a PR with the translation - it would be much appreciated.

Comment: but... I see ru lang files. Here are they at screenshot